# How to group two characters in java regular expression?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have to split a string using Java.

Suppose I have

```
"India, Russia, US,UK, Asia"
```

and i want output like

```
India 
Russia
US,Uk 
Asia
```

I mean i have to split it for the combination of "comma" and "space" only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the String `split` method. It takes a regular expression as parameter.
In your case, you want to match a comma and one space, therefore your regex is `",\\s"`.

```
String countries = "India, Russia, US,UK , Asia"
String[] countryArray = countries.split(",\\s");
```

Answer (score 2):

The string.[split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method should do what you need.

So, doing something like so, should work:

```
String str = "India, Russia, US,UK , Asia"
String[] countries = str.split(",\\s+");
```

This will split a string upon finding a comma followed by one or more spaces.

Answer (score 2):

> ***How to group two characters in java regular expression?***

You just put them after each other.

(This will *not* cause the split to split on either one of the characters. For that you need to put it in a character class `[...]`, or combine them with the or operator: `|`)

> ***I have to split it for the combination of "comma" and "space" only.***

Then put a comma, and then a space after each other:

```
str.split(", ");
```